# Kali linux 2.0 wlan0

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, debian, kali-linux, gnu

I executed the following command not knowing that it would disable the wireless option from my settings.

```
iw wlan0 del
```

Is there any way to reverse the command?
Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to find helpful information here on reconfiguring your wireless interface.

1. https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/iw

   - Use `iw phy phy0 interface add wlan0 type managed` to add the interface back. If the device is called something other than phy0, then substitute it in.
2. https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/iw/vif
3. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WiFiHowTo

   - Be aware that this is an Ubuntu support article, but it is also Debian based so it may provide help for managing wireless interfaces in Kali Linux.

Best of luck.

Comment: Answers with little more than a few links tend to suffer from link-rot. Please consider quoting some of these articles (with attribution!) or summarizing the important information, so that your post is still relevant, should the site go down, etc. Thanks for contributing!

Comment: Will do. Thank you for your suggestions, @studiohack!